# Is QGIS working on new Apple computers, Silicon M1 Processor

Tags: qgis, macos

Does QGIS work on the new M1 Apple processors? Is it working natively or with Rosetta emulation?

Comment: For hardware recommendations there is the [hardwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Currently running Big Sur 11.0.1 on Macbook Air with M1. QGis 3.16 starts without a problem. But I can't comment yet on the behavior in general. Will update as I use it during the week!

Comment: Any updates?;).

Comment: Sorry, sold the Air some time ago :D Went back to linux hehe

Comment: Haha, why? Just asking because I'm the same dilemma;)

Comment: Don't want to be too political in this, but just too much Apple for my taste, the system just differs enough from linux, that it slows my productivity (I consider myself a power user, lots of CLI and coding)